# How can a goblin attack and hide in the same turn?

Tags: dnd-5e, stealth

In the basic rules both an attack or going into hiding counts as an action, of which you can only do one per turn. But in the [demonstration video of the Starter Box](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hgNRe76o4_8) in the very first fight the group gets ambushed by goblins who are hidden, shoot arrows, and then go into hiding again in the same turn. Does WotC play their own game wrong, or is there a rule I missed that allows somebody to hide after an attack?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

On Page 58 of the Lost Mine of Phandelver in the D&D Starter Set. Goblins have a ability called Nifty Escape that allows them to disengage or hide as a bonus action.

Like D&D 4e the 5e monster stat block spells out any special abilities and exception to the normal rules.

Comment: Lucky you already having that D&D Starter Set. I will need to wait to July 17th for that.

Comment: If you have a gamestore that part of the Wizard Play Network (i.e. they host organized play events). You can get it now.

Answer (score 17):

The GM actually spells that out.  He says "Goblins, because they are particularly stealthy, can use their bonus action to hide."  Presumably, goblins have a racial feature that works like the Rogue's Cunning Action and allows them to use a bonus action to make a Hide action.