# Can I use cunning action to get away and hide right away?

Tags: dnd-5e, rogue, stealth

My question is about *Cunning Action*; can you use *Disengage* to move out of line of sight of an enemy, and then use *Hide,* all in the same turn?

Cunning Action (PHB p. 96)

> You can take a bonus action on each of your turns in combat. This action can be used only to take the Dash, Disengage, or Hide action.

Comment: Welcome to rpg.se! Please take a look at the [tour], it's a useful introduction to the site. You'll need to [edit] your question to indicate the RPG system (and edition, if applicable) you're using.

Comment: @Erudaki: do you *know* that OP is talking about 5e? I see you've edited that information in, but don't see how you know that to be the case. (Certainly the terms are suggestive, but I was waiting on the word of the original querent.)

Comment: Since it's been reopened let's see where this goes. @Erudaki It's unsafe assume the game and edition, since the same name may be shared by other games or editions.

Answer (score 10):

### Absolutely

On your turn you get one action, one bonus action and can move up to your movement allowance.

Therefore you can use an action to disengage, move to where you cannot be "seen clearly" and use your bonus action (Cunning Action) to hide, you can use any remaining movement after you hide, remaining hidden unless you approach an enemy.

See [How can a goblin attack and hide in the same turn?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/41931/how-can-a-goblin-attack-and-hide-in-the-same-turn)

Answer (score 5):

There is nothing stopping you from using your bonus action to Disengage and your action to Hide (or vice versa; you can't do both with the same action).

However, Disengage does not actually give you more movement; it simply allows you to move past or away from enemies without provoking an opportunity attack. Unless you are within 5 feet of an enemy (or on an adjacent square/hex, if you happen to be playing with miniatures on a battle grid), you don't need to Disengage to leave an enemy's sight. Moving behind an object that gives you cover, such as a tree trunk or cart, will most likely be sufficient.

Comment: Related: [Can I Ready an action to Disengage?](//rpg.stackexchange.com/q/74163)

Comment: Also I believe the Asker is asking if he can do both (disengage AND hide) when he uses the Cunning action. Perhaps you can make clarify that you can choose ONE of the cunning action options when you use it and you have to use your action to do the other.